# Geometric meaning of matrix $I -X$

Tags: matrices, geometry, linear-transformations

What is the geometric meaning of operation $I - X$ where $I \in R^{n\times n}$ and $X \in R^{n\times n}$ ? How is it different from original linear transformation by $X$?